# my jsoup can not selcet elements by some classes

Tags: android, jsoup

I try to parse the source file of a website called dgtle.com
In order to get the top news, I coded as :

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.dgtle.com").get();
    Elements blocks = doc.getElementsByClass("listcs1");
```

I got nothing but NullPointerExecption while doing this. But the Div with the class of　"listcs1" really exists. This troubles me and I'm wondering  whether anybody can help me deal with this.

Comment: When I tried to connect from my desktop to that url from Eclipse test code, it changed url to http://bbs.dgtle.com?mobile=yes, but it fails to load it for some reason. Maybe mobile site doesn't have that class ? I cannot know, because my test failed to load that content...

Answer (score 0):

Use a doc.select instead of getElementsByClass..

ex.

```
Elements blocks = doc.select("div.listcs1");
```

this will get all divs with the class of "listcs1"

Jsoup lists all of the selection combinations here: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax